# Just compare if is conversion correct

Tags: c, delphi

With the help of some users here, I finally terminated the conversion of this code from C:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define IS_IN_SEARCH(mb, offset) (mb->searchmask[(offset)/8] & (1<<((offset)%8)))
#define REMOVE_FROM_SEARCH(mb, offset)  mb->searchmask[(offset)/8] &= ~(1<<((offset)%8));

typedef struct _MEMBLOCK
{
  HANDLE hProc;
  unsigned char *addr;
  int size;
  unsigned char *buffer;

  unsigned char *searchmask;
  int matches;
  int data_size;

  struct _MEMBLOCK *next;
} MEMBLOCK;

typedef enum
{
  COND_UNCONDITIONAL, 
  COND_EQUALS, 

  COND_INCREASED,
  COND_DECREASED,
} SEARCH_CONDITION;

MEMBLOCK* create_memblock (HANDLE hProc, MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION *meminfo, int data_size)
{
  MEMBLOCK *mb = malloc(sizeof(MEMBLOCK));

  if (mb)
  {
    mb->hProc = hProc;
    mb->addr = meminfo->BaseAddress;
    mb->size = meminfo->RegionSize;
    mb->buffer = malloc(meminfo->RegionSize);
    mb->searchmask = malloc(meminfo->RegionSize/8);
    memset (mb->searchmask, 0xff, meminfo->RegionSize/8);
    mb->matches = meminfo->RegionSize;
    mb->next = NULL;
    mb->data_size = data_size;
  }
  return mb;
}

void free_memblock (MEMBLOCK *mb)
{
  if (mb)
  { 
    if (mb->buffer)
    {
      free(mb->buffer);
    }

    if (mb->searchmask)
    {
      free(mb->searchmask);
    }

    free (mb);
  } 
}

void update_memblock (MEMBLOCK *mb, SEARCH_CONDITION condition, unsigned int val)
{
     static unsigned char tempbuf[128*1024];
     unsigned int bytes_left;
     unsigned int total_read;
     unsigned int bytes_to_read;
     unsigned int bytes_read;

  if (mb->matches > 0)
  {

     bytes_left = mb->size;
     total_read = 0;
     mb->matches = 0;

     while (bytes_left)
     {
           bytes_to_read = (bytes_left > sizeof(tempbuf)) ?  sizeof(tempbuf) : bytes_left;
           ReadProcessMemory (mb->hProc, mb->addr + total_read, tempbuf, bytes_to_read, (DWORD*)&bytes_read);
           if (bytes_read != bytes_to_read) break;

           if (condition == COND_UNCONDITIONAL)
           {
               memset (mb->searchmask + (total_read/8), 0xff, bytes_read/8);
               mb->matches += bytes_read;
           }
           else
           {
               unsigned int offset;

               for (offset = 0; offset < bytes_read; offset += mb->data_size)
               {
                   if (IS_IN_SEARCH(mb, (total_read+offset)))
                   {
                      BOOL is_match = FALSE;
                      unsigned int temp_val;
                      unsigned int prev_val = 0;

                      switch (mb->data_size)
                      {
                          case 1:
                               temp_val = tempbuf[offset];
                               prev_val = *((unsigned char*)&mb->buffer[total_read+offset]);
                               break;
                          case 2:
                               temp_val = *((unsigned short*)&tempbuf[offset]);
                               prev_val = *((unsigned short*)&mb->buffer[total_read+offset]);
                               break;
                          case 4: 
                          default:
                               temp_val = *((unsigned int*)&tempbuf[offset]);
                               prev_val = *((unsigned int*)&mb->buffer[total_read+offset]);
                              break;
                      }

                      switch (condition)
                      {
                         case COND_EQUALS:
                              is_match = (temp_val == val);
                              break;
                         case COND_INCREASED:
                              is_match = (temp_val > prev_val);
                              break;
                         case COND_DECREASED:
                              is_match = (temp_val < prev_val);
                              break;
                         default: 
                              break;
                      }

                      if (is_match)
                      {
                        mb->matches++;
                      }
                      else
                      {
                        REMOVE_FROM_SEARCH(mb,(total_read+offset));
                      }

                   }
               }
           }

           memcpy (mb->buffer + total_read, tempbuf, bytes_read);

           bytes_left -= bytes_read;
           total_read += bytes_read;
     }

     mb->size = total_read;
  }   
}

MEMBLOCK* create_scan (unsigned int pid, int data_size)
{
  MEMBLOCK *mb_list = NULL;
  MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION meminfo;
  unsigned char *addr = 0;

  HANDLE hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pid);

  if (hProc)
  {
    while (1)
    {
      if (VirtualQueryEx (hProc, addr, &meminfo, sizeof(meminfo))==0)
      {
        break;
      }   

#define WRITABLE (PAGE_READWRITE | PAGE_WRITECOPY | PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE | PAGE_EXECUTE_WRITECOPY)

      if ((meminfo.State & MEM_COMMIT) && (meminfo.Protect & WRITABLE ))
      {   

        MEMBLOCK *mb = create_memblock(hProc, &meminfo, data_size);
        if (mb)
        {
//           update_memblock (mb);
           mb->next = mb_list;
           mb_list = mb;
        }
      } 
        addr = (unsigned char*)meminfo.BaseAddress + meminfo.RegionSize;
    }
  }

  return mb_list;
}

void free_scan (MEMBLOCK *mb_list)
{
     CloseHandle (mb_list->hProc);

     while (mb_list)
     {
           MEMBLOCK *mb = mb_list;
           mb_list = mb_list->next;
           free_memblock (mb);
     }
}

void update_scan (MEMBLOCK *mb_list, SEARCH_CONDITION condition, unsigned int val)
{
     MEMBLOCK *mb = mb_list;
     while (mb)
     {
           update_memblock (mb, condition, val);
           mb = mb->next;
     }
}

void dump_scan_info (MEMBLOCK *mb_list)
{
     MEMBLOCK *mb = mb_list;

     while (mb)
     {
           int i;
           printf ("0x%08x %d\r\n", mb->addr, mb->size);

           for (i = 0; i < mb->size; i++)
           {
               printf("%02x", mb->buffer[i]);
           }
           printf ("\r\n");

           mb = mb->next;
     }
}

void poke (HANDLE hProc, int data_size, unsigned int addr, unsigned int val)
{
     if (WriteProcessMemory (hProc, (void*)addr, &val, data_size, NULL) == 0)
     {
         printf("poke failed\r\n");
     }
}

unsigned int peek (HANDLE hProc, int data_size, unsigned int addr)
{
     unsigned int val = 0;

     if (ReadProcessMemory (hProc, (void*)addr, &val, data_size, NULL) == 0)
     { 
         printf("poke failed\r\n");
     }

     return val;
}

void print_matches (MEMBLOCK *mb_list)
{
     unsigned int offset;
     MEMBLOCK *mb = mb_list;

     while (mb)
     {
           for (offset = 0; offset < mb->size; offset+= mb->data_size)
           {
               if (IS_IN_SEARCH(mb, offset))
               {
                  unsigned int val = peek (mb->hProc, mb->data_size, (unsigned int)mb->addr + offset);
                  printf("0x%08x: 0x%08x (%d) \r\n", mb->addr + offset, val, val);
               }
           }

           mb = mb->next;
     }
}

int get_match_count (MEMBLOCK *mb_list)
{
    MEMBLOCK *mb = mb_list;
    int count = 0;

    while (mb)
    {
          count += mb->matches;
          mb = mb->next;
    }

    return count;
}

unsigned int str2int (char *s)
{
   int base = 10;

   if (s[0] == '0' && s[1] == 'x')
   {
     base = 16;
     s += 2;
   }

   return strtoul (s, NULL, base);
}

MEMBLOCK* ui_new_scan(void)
{
   MEMBLOCK *scan = NULL;
   DWORD pid;
   int data_size;
   unsigned int start_val;
   SEARCH_CONDITION start_cond;
   char s[20];

   while(1)
   {
           printf("\r\nEnter the pid: ");
           fgets (s, sizeof(s), stdin);
           pid = str2int(s);
           printf ("\r\nEnter the data size: ");
           fgets (s, sizeof(s), stdin);
           data_size = str2int(s);
           printf ("\r\nEnter the start value, or 'u' for unknown:  ");
           fgets (s, sizeof(s), stdin);
           if (s[0] == 'u')
           { 
              start_cond = COND_UNCONDITIONAL;
              start_val = 0;
           }
           else
           {
               start_cond = COND_EQUALS;
               start_val = str2int (s);
           }

           scan = create_scan (pid, data_size);
           if (scan) break;
           printf ("\r\nInvalid scan");
   }

   update_scan (scan, start_cond, start_val);
   printf("\r\n%d matches found\r\n", get_match_count(scan));

   return scan;       
}

void ui_poke (HANDLE hProc, int data_size)
{
     unsigned int addr;
     unsigned int val;
     char s[20];

     printf("Enter the address: ");
     fgets (s, sizeof(s), stdin);
     addr = str2int(s);

     printf("\r\nEnter the value: ");
     fgets (s, sizeof(s), stdin);
     val = str2int(s);
     printf ("\r\n");

     poke (hProc, data_size, addr, val);
}

void ui_run_scan(void)
{ 
     unsigned int val;
     char s[20];
     MEMBLOCK *scan;

     scan = ui_new_scan();

     while(1)
     {
        printf("\r\nEnter the next value or");
        printf("\r\n[i] increased");
        printf("\r\n[d] decreased");
        printf("\r\n[m] print matches");
        printf("\r\n[p] poke address");
        printf("\r\n[n] new scan");
        printf("\r\n[q] quit\r\n");

        fgets (s, sizeof(s), stdin);
        printf("\r\n" );

        switch(s[0])
        {
          case 'i':
               update_scan (scan, COND_INCREASED, 0);
               printf(" %d matches found\r\n", get_match_count(scan));
               break;
          case 'd':
               update_scan (scan, COND_DECREASED, 0);
               printf(" %d matches found\r\n", get_match_count(scan));
               break;
          case 'm':
               print_matches(scan);
               break;
          case 'p':
               ui_poke (scan->hProc, scan->data_size);
               break;
          case 'n':
               free_scan(scan);
               scan = ui_new_scan();
               break;
          case 'q':
               free_scan(scan);
               return;
          default:
               val = str2int(s);
               update_scan(scan, COND_EQUALS, val);
               printf(" %d matches found\r\n", get_match_count(scan));
               break;
        }
     }
} 

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
     ui_run_scan();
     return 0;
}
```

to Delphi:

```
//Declarations
type
 PMEMBLOCK = ^MEMBLOCK;
 MEMBLOCK = packed record
  hProc: THandle;
  addr: array of byte;
  size: integer;
  buffer: array of byte;
  searchmask: array of byte;
  matches: integer;
  data_size: integer;
  next: array of PMEMBLOCK;
end;

type
 SEARCH_CONDITION = (COND_UNCONDITIONAL, COND_EQUALS, COND_INCREASED, COND_DECREASED);

const
 WRITABLE = (PAGE_READWRITE and PAGE_WRITECOPY and PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE and PAGE_EXECUTE_WRITECOPY);

function Is_In_Search(mb: PMEMBLOCK; offset: cardinal): Boolean;
begin
  Result := 0 <> (mb.searchmask[offset div 8] and (1 shl (offset mod 8)));
end;

procedure Remove_From_Search(mb: PMEMBLOCK; offset: cardinal);
begin
  mb.searchmask[offset div 8] := mb.searchmask[offset div 8] and not (1 shl (offset mod 8));
end;


function create_memblock(hProc: THandle; meminfo: MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION; data_size: integer): PMemblock;
var
 mb: PMemblock;
 x:integer;
begin
x:= round(meminfo.RegionSize/8);
 mb:= malloc(sizeof(MEMBLOCK));
 if mb<>ptr(0) then begin
  mb.hProc := hProc;
  mb.addr := meminfo.BaseAddress;
  mb.size := meminfo.RegionSize;
  mb.buffer := malloc(meminfo.RegionSize);
  mb.searchmask := malloc(x);
  memset(mb.searchmask, $ff, x);
  mb.matches := meminfo.RegionSize;  
  mb.next := NULL;
  mb.data_size := data_size;
 end;
 result := mb;
end;

procedure free_memblock(mb:pmemblock);
begin
 if mb<>ptr(0) then begin
  if mb.buffer<>ptr(0) then free(mb.buffer);
  if mb.searchmask<>ptr(0) then free(mb.searchmask);
  mb:=nil;
 end;
end;

procedure update_memblock(mb:pmemblock; condition:SEARCH_CONDITION; val:cardinal);
var
 tempbuf: array[0..(128*1024)-1] of Byte;
 bytes_left: cardinal;
 total_read: cardinal;
 bytes_to_read: cardinal;
 bytes_read: cardinal;
 offset: cardinal;
 x, z:integer;
 is_match: boolean;
 temp_val, prev_val: cardinal;
begin
 if mb.matches > 0 then begin
  bytes_left := mb.size;
  total_read := 0;
  mb.matches := 0;
  while (bytes_left<>0) do begin
   if bytes_left > sizeof(tempbuf) then bytes_to_read := sizeof(tempbuf) else bytes_to_read := bytes_left;
   //TO USE IN DLL: tempbuf[0] :=  PBYTE(dword(mb.addr)+total_read)^; // bytes_to_read = 1bytes  {PRECISA CRIAR IF PROS OUTROS TIPOS}
   ReadProcessMemory(mb.hProc, pointer(dword(mb.addr)+total_read), @tempbuf, bytes_to_read, dword(bytes_to_read));

   if bytes_read <> bytes_to_read then break;

   if condition = COND_UNCONDITIONAL then begin
    x:= round(total_read/8);   
    z:= round(bytes_read/8);
    memset (pointer(dword(mb.searchmask) + x), $ff, z);
    mb.matches :=+ bytes_read;
   end
   else
   begin
     offset:=0;
     while (offset < bytes_read) do
     begin

       if IS_IN_SEARCH(mb, (total_read+offset)) then begin
        is_match:=false;
        prev_val := 0;
       end;

       case mb.data_size of
       1: begin
            temp_val := tempbuf[offset];
            prev_val := PBYTE(mb.buffer[total_read+offset])^;
            break;
          end;     
       2: begin  
            temp_val := PWORD(tempbuf[offset])^;
            prev_val := PWORD(mb.buffer[total_read+offset])^;
            break;
          end;
       4: begin   
            temp_val := PDWORD(tempbuf[offset])^;
            prev_val := PDWORD(mb.buffer[total_read+offset])^;
            break;
          end;
       end;

       case condition of
          COND_EQUALS: begin
                        is_match := temp_val = val;
                        break;
                       end;
       COND_INCREASED: begin
                        is_match := (temp_val > prev_val);
                        break;
                       end;
       COND_DECREASED: begin
                        is_match := (temp_val < prev_val);
                        break;
                       end;
       end;

       if (is_match) then
        inc(mb.matches)
       else
        REMOVE_FROM_SEARCH(mb,(total_read+offset));

        bytes_left :=- bytes_read;
        total_read :=+ bytes_read;

      Inc(offset, mb.data_size);
     end;
   end;

    memcpy(pointer(dword(mb.buffer) + total_read), @tempbuf, bytes_read);

  end;
  mb.size := total_read;
 end;
end;

function create_scan(pid: cardinal; data_size: integer):PMEMBLOCK;
var
 mb_list: PMEMBLOCK;
 meminfo: MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION;
 addr: PBYTE;
 hProc: THandle;
 mb: PMEMBLOCK;
begin
 mb_list:=nil;
 addr:=nil;
 hProc := OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pid);
 if hProc<>0 then begin
  while 1<>0 do begin
    if VirtualQueryEx(hProc, pointer(addr), meminfo, sizeof(meminfo))=0 then break;

     if ((meminfo.State = MEM_COMMIT) and (meminfo.Protect = WRITABLE )) then begin
      mb := create_memblock(hProc, meminfo, data_size);
      if mb<>ptr(0) then begin
            mb.next := @mb_list;
            mb_list := mb;
      end;
     end;
     addr := pbyte(dword(meminfo.BaseAddress) + dword(meminfo.RegionSize));
  end;
 end;
 result := mb_list;
end;


procedure free_scan(mb_list: PMEMBLOCK);
var
 mb: PMEMBLOCK;
begin
     CloseHandle(mb_list.hProc);

     while mb_list<>ptr(0) do
      begin
           mb := mb_list;
           mb_list := @mb_list.next;
           free_memblock(mb);
     end;
end;

procedure update_scan(mb_list: PMEMBLOCK; condition: SEARCH_CONDITION; val: cardinal);
var
 mb: PMEMBLOCK;
begin
     mb := mb_list;
     while mb<>ptr(0) do
     begin
           update_memblock(mb, condition, val);
           mb := @mb.next;
     end;
end;


procedure dump_scan_info(mb_list: PMEMBLOCK);
var
 mb: PMEMBLOCK;
 i: integer;
begin
     mb := mb_list;
     while mb<>ptr(0) do
     begin
           writeln(Format('0x%08x %d',[mb.addr, mb.size]));

           for i := 0 to mb.size do
           begin
               writeln(Format('%02x',[mb.buffer[i]]));
           end;
           writeln('');

           mb := @mb.next;
     end;
end;

procedure poke(hProc:THANDLE; data_size: integer; addr: cardinal; val: cardinal);
var
 write: cardinal;
begin
 if not ReadProcessMemory(hProc, pointer(addr), @val, data_size, write) then
  writeln('poke failed');
end;

function peek(hProc: THandle; data_size: integer; addr: cardinal):cardinal;
var
 val: cardinal;
 write: cardinal;
begin
 val := 0;

 if not ReadProcessMemory(hProc, pointer(addr), @val, data_size, write) then
   writeln('poke failed');


 result := val;
end;

procedure print_matches(mb_list: PMEMBLOCK);
var
 offset: cardinal;
 mb: PMEMBLOCK;
 val: cardinal;
begin
     mb := mb_list;

     while mb<>ptr(0) do
     begin
           offset:=0;
           while (offset<mb.size) do
           begin

               if IS_IN_SEARCH(mb, offset) then begin
                  val := peek(mb.hProc, mb.data_size, dword(dword(mb.addr) + offset));
                  writeln(format('0x%08x: 0x%08x (%d)',[dword(dword(mb.addr) + offset), val]));
               end;

           Inc(offset, mb.data_size);
           end;

           mb := @mb.next;
     end;
end;

function get_match_count(mb_list: PMEMBLOCK): integer;
var
 mb: PMEMBLOCK;
 count: integer;
begin
    mb := mb_list;
    count := 0;

    while mb<>ptr(0) do
    begin
          count :=+ mb.matches;
          mb := @mb.next;
    end;

    Result := count;
end;

function ui_new_scan: PMEMBLOCK;
var
 scan: PMEMBLOCK;
 pid: dword;
 data_size: integer;
 start_val: cardinal;
 start_cond: SEARCH_CONDITION;
 s: array [0..19] of char;
begin
 scan := nil;

 while 1<>0 do
 begin
  writeln('Digite o pid: ');
  readln(s);
  pid := strtoint(s);
  writeln('Enter the data size: ');
  readln(s);
  data_size := strtoint(s);
  writeln('Enter the start value, or ''u'' for unknown:  ');
  readln(s);
  if s[0] = 'u' then begin
   start_cond := COND_UNCONDITIONAL;
   start_val := 0;
  end else
  begin
   start_cond := COND_EQUALS;
   start_val := strtoint(s);
  end;
   scan := create_scan (pid, data_size);
   if scan<>ptr(0) then break;
   writeln('Invalid scan');
 end;
   update_scan(scan, start_cond, start_val);
   writeln(Format('%d matches found', [get_match_count(scan)]));

   Result := scan;
end;

procedure ui_poke(hProc: THandle; data_size: integer);
var
 addr: cardinal;
 val: cardinal;
 s: array [0..19] of char;
begin        
  writeln('Enter the address: ');
  readln(s);
  addr := strtoint(s);
  writeln('Enter the value: ');
  readln(s);
  val := strtoint(s);
  writeln('');
  poke(hProc, data_size, addr, val);
end;

function CaseOfString(s: string; a: array of string): Integer;
begin
  Result := 0;
  while (Result < Length(a)) and (a[Result] <> s) do
    Inc(Result);
  if a[Result] <> s then
    Result := -1;
end;

procedure ui_run_scan;
var
 val: cardinal;
 s: array [0..19] of char;
 scan: PMEMBLOCK;
begin
 scan := ui_new_scan();

 while 1<>0 do
 begin
   writeln('Enter the next value or');
   writeln('[i] increased');
   writeln('[d] decreased');
   writeln('[m] print matches');
   writeln('[p] poke address');
   writeln('[n] new scan');
   writeln('[q] quit');

   readln(s);

   if s[0] = 'i' then begin
    update_scan(scan, COND_INCREASED, 0);
    writeln(Format(' %d matches found', [get_match_count(scan)]));
    break;
   end;  

   if s[0] = 'd' then begin
    update_scan(scan, COND_DECREASED, 0);
    writeln(Format(' %d matches found', [get_match_count(scan)]));
    break;
   end;

   if s[0] = 'm' then begin
    print_matches(scan);
    break;
   end;

   if s[0] = 'p' then begin
    ui_poke (scan.hProc, scan.data_size);
    break;
   end;

   if s[0] = 'n' then begin
     free_scan(scan);
     scan := ui_new_scan();
    break;
   end; 

   if s[0] = 'q' then begin
    free_scan(scan);
    exit;
   end;

   if s[0] = 'p' then begin
    ui_poke (scan.hProc, scan.data_size);
    break;
   end;

   if (s[0]<>'i') and (s[0]<>'d') and (s[0]<>'m') and (s[0]<>'p') and (s[0]<>'n') and (s[0]<>'q') then begin
     val := strtoint(s);
     update_scan(scan, COND_EQUALS, val);
     writeln(Format('%d matches found', [get_match_count(scan)]));
     break;
   end;
 end;
end;

procedure Main;
begin
 ui_run_scan();
end;
```

Please, can anyone just check if is the conversion correct? Thank you so much.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review - please check out the [FAQ]. We ask that you put your code in the post, because it makes it a lot easier for us to review it. For example, I can't even get to your code right now - blocked.

Comment: Do you have unit tests on the old code? Obviously you can't just run the old tests against the new code, but they could give you a set of tests to write.

Comment: Dear Michael, Unfortunetly, I'm with problems...
Every time returns "Invalid scan" :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First problem: `MEMBLOCK::next` in C is a pointer to a single `MEMBLOCK`, but in your Delphi code, it's an *array* of pointers. Declare it as a `PMemBlock` instead.

The C definition of `WRITABLE` combines flags with the *or* operator, but your Delphi code uses *and*, virtually guaranteeing that the result will be zero instead of whatever combination of bits it's supposed to be.

Please don't use `Ptr(0)` when Delphi already has a perfectly good value to represent the null pointer. Use `nil` instead.

If you're going to use `malloc` in Delphi, then you can't use it to assign special Delphi-managed types like dynamic arrays. A dynamic array isn't just a pointer to a block of bytes. The block of bytes requires a specific structure, and the pointer isn't even to the *start* of the block. If you use `malloc`, then change the declarations of `addr`, `buffer`, and `searchmask` to have type `PByte`. (This especially applies to `addr` since it gets assigned an ordinary pointer, not an array.)

If this code requires binary compatibility with the C code — that is, if this code is going to be used in combination with code that's already compiled to use the C code, so everything the Delphi code produces has to have the same layout in memory — then you can' use dynamic arrays at all. However, if you're just translating this code for use in a Delphi project and don't require identical layout, then you can keep the dynamic arrays and reduce your use of `malloc` instead. In `create_memblock`, for example, you could use `New` and `SetLength`:

```
function create_memblock(hProc: THandle; meminfo: MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION; data_size: integer): PMemBlock;
var
  x: integer;
begin
  x := meminfo.RegionSize div 8; // don't use floating-point division if you don't have to
  try
    New(Result);
    Result.hProc := hProc;
    Result.addr := meminfo.BaseAddress;
    Result.size := meminfo.RegionSize;
    SetLength(Result.buffer, meminfo.RegionSize);
    SetLength(Result.searchmask, x);
    memset(mb.searchmask, $ff, x);
    Result.matches := meminfo.RegionSize;  
    Result.next := nil; // "Null" isn't what you think it is in Delphi
    Result.data_size := data_size;
  except
    on EOutOfMemory do
      Result := nil;
  end;
end;
```

Depending on how fancy you want to get, you could even make `MemBlock` be a class, and then turn `create_memblock` into a `MemBlock.Create` constructor.

Be careful about your use of `free`. You haven't shown the definition of `malloc` in your Delphi code, but if it's anything other than a thin wrapper for `GetMem`, then you're in for some problems because `System.Free` expects plain memory blocks allocated with `GetMem`, not whatever `malloc` returns. If you're importing `malloc` from the C runtime library, then you need to make sure you're calling the `free` function from that same library, not Delphi's `Free`. I'd import `free` with a different name, if that's the case.

Speaking of `free`, the C version of `free_memblock` calls `free(mb)`, whereas your Delphi version just assigns `nil` to it, which is particularly ineffective since `mb` is a local variable that goes out of scope at the next instruction, so you not only fail to free the memory, but also assign a value into a memory location that ceases to exist anymore. Call `Free(mb)` instead. Also, `free` is always safe to call on null pointers, so you don't need to check before calling it. The C code makes the same mistake.

The C code uses the conditional operator to assign to `bytes_to_read` in `update_memblock`, but in Delphi, it can be written more concisely with the `Min` function from the `Math` unit:

```
bytes_to_read := Min(SizeOf(tmpbuf), bytes_left);
```

Instead of temporary variables and `Round`, you can just use the `div` operator. It works the same way as C's `/` operator on integers.

The `+=` operator in `mb->matches += bytes_read` increments the left operand by the right operand. You've translated it as `:=+`, which isn't the same at all. Use Delphi's `Inc` instruction instead:

```
Inc(mb.matches, bytes_read);
```

The block after the C code's first call to `IS_IN_SEARCH` extends all the way to *include* both the following `switch` statements and the `if`, but your Delphi code ends the block after just the two assignment statements. That's just sloppy. Make sure you proofread your code.

Do not call `break` instead a Delphi `case` statement. It's necessary in the C `switch` statement because control will "fal through" into the next case, but that doesn't happen in Delphi, so the `break` actually applies to the `while` loop instead. Delphi will break out of the `case` statement automatically, so don't use `break` there.

You've incorrectly translated `*((unsigned char*)&mb->buffer[total_read+offset])` to `PBYTE(mb.buffer[total_read+offset])^`. The C code has an extra pointer reference, which you omit in the Delphi code. In this case, the casting isn't necessary at all since `buffer` is *already* an array of bytes, but it's important in the subsequent cases where the pointer gets type-cast to a larger type. Use the `@` operator where the C code uses `&` to get this: `PBYTE(@mb.buffer[total_read+offset])^`.

The `memcpy` call near the bottom of `update_memblock` occurs in an entirely different place in the two versions of the function. Again, proofreading.

In `create_scan`, you're using `=` where the original code used `&`. Those are two completely different tests. You're testing for equality when you should be performing a bitwise mask. Write `(meminfo.State and MEM_COMMIT) <> 0` to check whether the `State` field shares any of the same bits as are in `MEM_COMMIT`. Likewise for `Protect` and `WRITABLE`.

You assign `mb.next := @mb_list`, which is wrong. The `next` field shouldn't get a pointer to the `mb_list` variable; it should get the *contents* of the variable, as the C code does. The same when you assign `mb_list := @mb_list.next`. The compiler can help you find such errors. Go to your compiler options and turn on the "typed @ operator" setting.

The `for` loop in `dump_scan_info` goes one element too far, and inside the loop, you call `writeln` when you should call `write`; you're adding line breaks where the C code never printed them.

In `ui_run_scan`, you've gotten confused by the C code's use of characters in the `switch` statement. Delphi can do the same thing because one-character strings are really `Char`, so they're ordinal types and thus acceptable inside `case` statements. You can write your code the same as the C code (but without the `break` statements, remember):

```
case s[0] of
  'i': begin
    update_scan(scan, COND_INCREASED, 0);
    writeln(Format(' %d matches found', [get_match_count(scan)]);
  end;
  'd': begin
    update_scan(scan, COND_DECREASED, 0);
    writeln(Format(' %d matches found', [get_match_count(scan)]);
  end;
  'm': print_matches(scan);
  'p': ui_poke(scan.hProc, scan.data_size);
  'n': begin
    free_scan(scan);
    scan = ui_new_scan;
  end;
  'q': begin
    free_scan(scan);
    exit;
  end;
  else begin
    val = StrToInt(s);
    update_scan(scan, COND_EQUALS, val);
    writeln(Format(' %d matches found', [get_match_count(scan)]);
  end;
end;
```